# How do I insert empty lines in text output?

Tags: python

Just started my first comp sci class this summer and need some help.

Our assignment is to make a stock transaction program (irrelevant), and im having trouble with 2 things.

1. Is there anyway to split the input section from the output (Don't know the official terms). Here is an example from my professors program. Mine doesn't split like this. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWnve.png)
2. whenever I open my .py file from the file explorer, it crashes after the 6th input. Whenever I run it from the cmd directly (python "file name") or in IDLE it works fine so I am confused.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code and and what it looks like in CMD. [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPmzn.png)

```
# This program will be used to determine
# Calculations for a stock transaction

# The inputs
Shares_Bought = int(input('Enter shares purchased: '))
SharePrice_B = float(input('Enter purchase price of shares: '))
B_Commission = float(input('Enter broker buy commission: '))
Shares_Sold = int(input('Enter shares sold: '))
SharePrice_S = float(input('Enter sell price of shares: '))
S_Commission = float(input('Enter broker sell comission: '))

#CONSTANTS?
TOTAL_PURCHASE = Shares_Bought * SharePrice_B
TOTAL_SALE = Shares_Sold * SharePrice_S
TOTAL_SALES_COMMISSION = (Shares_Bought * SharePrice_B) * (B_Commission / 100) + (Shares_Sold * SharePrice_S) * (S_Commission / 100)



# The outputs 
print('Alex Partida Stock Transaction App')
print(f'Joe Paid: ${Shares_Bought * SharePrice_B:,.2f}')
print(f'Purchase Commission: ${(Shares_Bought * SharePrice_B) * (B_Commission / 100):,.2f}')        # Need to make this shorter/split into more lines
print(f'Joe sold at: ${Shares_Sold * SharePrice_S:,.2f}')
print(f'Sales Commission: ${(Shares_Sold * SharePrice_S) * (S_Commission / 100):,.2f}')
print(f"Joe's Profit: ${(TOTAL_SALE - TOTAL_PURCHASE) - TOTAL_SALES_COMMISSION:,.2f}")
```

enter code here

Comment: Hey, the first issue you can use `print()` to split (technically, speaking adding an empty line) on top of the outputs.
And the second one if you share the crash error it will be easier to understood. How you are opening from file explorer? Are you double clicking or using open with IDLE?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - I renamed your question, please keep your text and titles factual and to the point; don't apologise, greet, or otherwise chat in those areas. Your question is supposed to get you an answer, but also be useful others, and something like "Stupid" helps nobody. No such thing as a dumb question - however, you *should* at least look for an answer on SO first and in this case your question is the exact same as the one I linked.

Comment: @5war00p Hey, thank you so much for the response. I figured out the first issue with ur help. As for the 2nd issue, there isn't any crash error or anything. I just double click it from file explorer and then after the 6th input it just closes.

Comment: Ah, understood, you cannot simply double click and run the python program.
You have to do it from command prompt by using `python "file_name"` or open with IDLE and run it.

Comment: @5war00p Ohh okay. Thanks for that information. My professor said one of the requirements was to have it run from the file explorer so I guess I just misunderstood him (or he gave bad directions lol). Anyway thanks for all the help! It is much appreciated!